# How can I set colspan depending on hidden-xs a column using Bootstrap?

Tags: html-table, bootstrap-4

I have a table with a dynamic row which I hide one of its columns using bootstrap `hidden-xs`. The next row which is footer is using `colspan`.

I wonder if it's possible to set the number of `colspan` depending on `screen-size (hidden-xs).

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    {% for product in products %}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left hidden-xs"><a href="{{ product.href }}">{{ product.name }}</a></td>
        <td class="text-left">{{ product.model }}</td>
        <td>{% for option in product.option %}
            {% if option.type != 'file' %}
            <div><small><span class="hidden-xs">{{ option.name }}: </span>{{ option.value }}</small></div>
            {% else %}
            <div><small><span class="hidden-xs">{{ option.name }}: </span><a href="{{ option.href }}">{{ option.value }}</a></small></div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ product.quantity }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ product.price }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ product.total }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for total in totals %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="text-right">{{ total.title }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ total.text }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
<tbody>
```

**UPDATE**
For now such an approach came to my mind:

```
<tr class="hidden-xs">
    <td colspan="5" class="text-right">{{ total.title }}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{ total.text }}</td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden-xl hidden-lg hidden-sm">
    <td colspan="4" class="text-right">{{ total.title }}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{ total.text }}</td>
</tr>
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: @Kardo: do you know which column would be hidden at which breakpoint at design time? Since it seems like you're using some kind of scripting language from the server-side, if we know how many columns would be hidden for which breakpoint, then the colspan could be calculated based on that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Bootstrap 4 doesn't have a `hidden-xs` class. In fact, it doesn't have any type of `hidden-*` utility. Unless you defined such utilities yourself, you should probably use `d-none d-sm-table-cell` classes instead of `hidden-xs`.

Documented [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)

---

To your question, you can't set `colspan` responsively on a `<td>` using CSS.

The proper way to do it is to use JavaScript, along these lines:

```js
const isXs = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 576px)')
const changeColspans = () =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.variable-colspan')].forEach((cell) => {
    cell.setAttribute('colspan', isXs.matches ? 2 : 4)
  })
changeColspans()
window.addEventListener('resize', changeColspans)
```

where `2` and `4` are the colspan values you want to set to `colspan` when `isXs.matches` is `true`/`false`. You'll need to add `variable-colspan` class to each cell you want to change.

---

If you really want to stay away from a JS solution, for whatever reason, you could work around it, by creating a separate `<td>` for each case and using Bootstrap's display utilities (linked above) to display the appropriate one on the current responsiveness interval. Generic example:

```html
  <td coslapn="2" class="d-sm-none">I render on xs only</td>
  <td colspan="4" class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">I render on sm and above</td>
```

---

The advantage of using JS here is that you don't need to swap DOM elements which has the potential to lose events bound on the element or generate rendering performance issues, on larger tables. These issues can be addressed, of course, but it's better not to have them in the first place.
JS can also easily handle multiple cases, whereas with the CSS workaround you need a separate element for each case.